# Is it possible to assign document type value in xslt variable?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I want to assign variable value on the condition, like below:

```
<xsl:variable name="publicationDoc" 
  select="document(@ID)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data
          /tcm:Content/em:PublicationData" />
<xsl:variable name="CountryCompId" 
  select="substring-after(
            $publicationDoc/em:Country/@xlink:href,
            '-')" />

<xsl:variable name="countryIdLocal">
  tcm:<xsl:value-of select="$publicationDoc/em:PubID" 
    />-<xsl:value-of 
    select="substring-after($publicationDoc
              /em:Country/@xlink:href,'-')" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="countryId">
  tcm:<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(
    substring-after($publication,'-'),'-')" 
  />-<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(
     $publicationDoc/em:Country/@xlink:href,'-')" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="countryLocal">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$CountryCompId != '' ">
      <xsl:value-of select="document(
         $countryIdLocal)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data
         /tcm:Content/em:Country" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="''" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="country">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$CountryCompId !='' ">
      <xsl:value-of select="document($countryId)
        /tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:Country" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="''" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

//Above I am assigning value on the basis of condition , however it gives below error while I try to transform "**To use a result tree fragment in a path expression, first convert it to a node-set using the msxsl:node-set() function"**

Seems assigning document type values to variable doesn't work. (`<xsl:value-of select="document($countryId)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:Country" />`)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any reason not to follow the advice given in the error message?  In XSLT 1.0, XPath expressions cannot be evaluated against dynamically created elements, only against the input document or against statically known XML.  The node-set() extension implemented by many XSLT 1.0 processors allows it, but in order to make use of it, you must invoke it.

Comment: Yes I tried to use the above suggestion, however my variable value become empty.

Comment: This particular fragment of code _isn't_ trying to "use a result tree fragment in a path expression" - are you sure this is actually the part of your stylesheet that causes the error?

Comment: Yes Ian, the problem is that when this variable has got invalid data (<xsl:variable name="CountryCompId" 
  select="substring-after(
            $publicationDoc/em:Country/@xlink:href,
            '-')" />)...then it gives error on (<xsl:value-of select="document(
         $countryIdLocal)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data
         /tcm:Content/em:Country" />)...seems converting document gives error.

Comment: That error message _should_ only happen if you've used a result tree fragment variable (i.e. one where the defining `xsl:variable` has a body instead of a `select` attribute) on the immediate left of a `/`, e.g. `$countryIdLocal/something`.  Are you trying to do this anywhere else in your stylesheet?

Comment: The spec for `document` says that when its argument is a node set then the result is the union of applying `document` to the string value of each node in the set in turn, and when the argument is _not_ a node set then the result is the root node of the document named by the string value of the argument.  An RTF is not a node set but maybe your processor is mistakenly trying to treat it as one, you could try forcing the string conversion yourself using `document(string($countryIdLocal))` and see if that helps.

Comment: Actually, given your `$countryIdLocal` has leading whitespace you'll probably _have_ to do `document(normalize-space($countryIdLocal))` to get it to work, otherwise it'll be trying to load a file named newline-space-space-tcm:....